# joining midpoints of a histogram by line

Tags: python, matplotlib

how do i take a midpoint of each bar in a histogram and draw a line joining those midpoints using matplotlib.

Here is sample data

```
test_scores = [55,45,88,75,43,56,89,98,55,54,65,77,88,81,82,89,92,98,65,\
               76,76,73,72,84] 
test_scores1 = [55,45,88,73,43,55,89,98,44,54,65,77,80,81,84,89,92,98,65,\
                71,75,73,70,81] 
bins = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
plt.hist(test_scores, bins, histtype='bar') 
plt.hist(test_scores1, bins, histtype='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: please read the SO guide how to ask question. Don't put the your home work directly on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hist()` function returns edges of the bins and their heights. We can use it to compute the centers of the bars and join them into a line as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_scores = [55,45,88,75,43,56,89,98,55,54,65,77,88,81,82,89,92,98,65,\
               76,76,73,72,84] 
test_scores1 = [55,45,88,73,43,55,89,98,44,54,65,77,80,81,84,89,92,98,65,\
                71,75,73,70,81] 
bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

#y,edges,_ = plt.hist(test_scores1, bins)
y,edges = np.histogram(test_scores1, bins)
centers = 0.5*(edges[1:]+ edges[:-1])
plt.plot(centers,y,'-*')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks better but can i get rid of histogram completely and just have the line. And is it possible to smothen the edges i.e midpoints..

Comment: We can use `numpy.histogram()` to do the binning for us. I have updated my answer. I did not understand what you mean by smoothening the edges.

Comment: Ignore my comment on smoothing the edges. Thanks for your help.